# Find semantic markup tags using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find semantic markup tags using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header">Header</header>
<footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
```

I tried all following code but it is not working:

```
jQuery(this).find("header")
jQuery(this).find("#header")
```

Comment: what is `jQuery(this)` referring to?

Comment: juse use `jQuery("#header")` or `jQuery("#footer")`

Comment: @guradio ohk, I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Comment: is this working on your browser https://jsfiddle.net/dLtzLuyv/?

Comment: @madalinivascu, yes it is working.

Comment: then it should work in your site too

Comment: @JeetenParmar can you check console for errors?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I am thinking same but dnt know why it is not working.

Comment: @guradio, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping you code under document.ready function

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was calling function from code behind. After putting all code in `document.ready` function inside function and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

what about this `$('header,footer,#header,#footer')` why wouldn't this be working?

Comment: I don't know, what is the wrong. If it is `div` tag then it is working fine.